# Tool for purging unneeded backups

Tags: linux, backup

I'm in the common situation where the one of the linux servers I use for storing backups is filling up. I'm wondering what tools are available for doing this.

Ideally, what I would like is something that keeps nightlies for the previous month, weeklies for the 2nd to 5th preceding months and retains monthlies (well, every 3rd week) for an indefinite period. Everything that falls outside of that would be deleted after the backups are run.

I could write a script to do this, but I feel like there must be a standard tool for this task.

Comment: There is no standard tool for this.  It's easy enough to do, however with a series of crontab entries which invoke the `find` program with the `-delete` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will do better with a custom script. You can maybe use [bacula](http://www.bacula.org) to manage all your backups and it will take care of that, but that may be overkill.

Comment: I think I will end up writing a script.

Comment: It's what I recommend. `find` is your friend :)